# How to add external user to FBA?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, membership-provider

Say I have 10 users (name, email, phone). How do I add them to FBA so they can use sharepoint which is configured to FBA?

I mean do I need to go to SQL box and add each member. (I know from site permission you can add users but I am not if the users should be present in the sql member database before I do this).

I went to site collection> permission but didn't see anything that says "add external user" or add fba user.

SharePoint 2010; FBA

Is there a tool in microsoft .net directory? I can't download and install this https://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com/documentation? codeplex feature so that's not an option. Also, we have to set this users up front.

Comment: Did you configure FBA yourself? Can you provide more details? Why can't you install SharePoint 2010 FBA Pack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint does support forms-based authentication but FBA is not something you get out-of-the-box.

If your implementation of FBA does not provide a UI to manage the users:

- add/modify/delete them directly in the Membership database
- use the ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool (you can run it by clicking *ASP.NET Configuration* from the *Website* menu in Visual Studio or without VS - [Managing ASP.NET Membership and Roles without Visual Studio](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/06/28/managing-asp-net-membership-and-roles-without-visual-studio/)).

Comment: Hi Marek, Actuall I ended up using the codeplex FBA management tool. It's much easier that way. https://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com/documentation